# How to Get Log in .txt when we close application from Process Tab in the Task Manager

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I make a Windows application , i run it.
Then i close that application from TaskManger from the APPLICATION TAB and click on the END TASK BUtton. then my LOG in .txt has successfully created.
Then their is another TAB called PROCESS TAB in the Task MAnager , but when i end the process of that application then my log file is not created.

Here is my Code.

```
    public  bool eventHandled;
    private int elapsedTime;
    public Form1()
    {
        elapsedTime = 0;
        InitializeComponent();
       //From here Log created when we click from application atb
        this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(300, 300);
            this.Text = "Form1";
            LogWrite("Application Start At :");
    }

  public static void LogWrite(string logMessage){
                   try     {                
       string path = @"D:\oldCode\log.txt";               
        if (!File.Exists(path))                
               {
                File.Create(path);
                TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(path);
                tw.Close();
            }

            using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText(path))
            {
                Log(logMessage, w);
            }
        } 
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
    //event handler for termination of a process

    public static void Log(string logMessage, TextWriter txtWriter)
    {
        try
        {
            txtWriter.Write("\r\n"+logMessage);
            txtWriter.WriteLine("{0} {1}", DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString(),
                DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString());
            //txtWriter.WriteLine("  :");
            //txtWriter.WriteLine("  :{0}", logMessage);
            txtWriter.WriteLine("-------------------------------");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
     class MyApplicationContext : ApplicationContext {

    private int formCount;
    private Form1 form1;
    private Rectangle form1Position;
    ////private FileStream userData;

    private MyApplicationContext() {
        formCount = 0;

        // Handle the ApplicationExit event to know when the application is exiting.
        Application.ApplicationExit += new EventHandler(this.OnApplicationExit);

        // Create both application forms and handle the Closed event 
        // to know when both forms are closed.
        form1 = new Form1();
        form1.Closed += new EventHandler(OnFormClosed);            
        form1.Closing += new CancelEventHandler(OnFormClosing);
     //   form1.Closing += new CancelEventHandler(onprocesscloase);
        formCount++;


        // Get the form positions based upon the user specific data. 

        form1.Show();

        // this is for PROCESS to kill it
         Process myProcess = new Process();
        myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "";
        myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        myProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        myProcess.Exited += new EventHandler(myProcesses_Exited);

    }

          //METHOD TO KILL PROCESS
    private void myProcesses_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Process ps = (Process) sender;
        //messageBox.Text = ps.ProcessName;
        //messageBox.Text = " has exited";
        //  MessageBox.Show("Exited event caught");
        LogWrite("Application Start At :");
       // myProcess.CloseMainWindow();
    }
    private void OnApplicationExit(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        // When the application is exiting, write the application data to the 
        // user file and close it.

    }
    private void OnFormClosing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e) {
        // When a form is closing, remember the form position so it 
        // can be saved in the user data file. 
        if (sender is Form1) 
            form1Position = ((Form)sender).Bounds;

    }

    private void OnFormClosed(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        // When a form is closed, decrement the count of open forms. 

        // When the count gets to 0, exit the app by calling 
        // ExitThread().
        formCount--;
        if (formCount == 0) {
            LogWrite("Application End At :");
            ExitThread();
        }
    }

    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args) {

        // Create the MyApplicationContext, that derives from ApplicationContext, 
        // that manages when the application should exit.

        MyApplicationContext context = new MyApplicationContext();

        // Run the application with the specific context. It will exit when 
        // all forms are closed.
        Application.Run(context);

    }

}
```

Comment: Abligh can u help me to get the event on the END PROCESS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lev is correct.  When you click End Task from the Application tab, Windows sends a WM_CLOSE message to your application.  This is the same as if you had clicked the red X close button or if you had called Me.Close on the main form of your application.  When this happens, your Form Closing events are fired and your application can gracefully shut down.

When you click the End Process button from the Processes tab, Windows just kills your process and no events are fired.

You can verify this by running Spy++ and have it monitor the messages sent to your application.  When you terminate the app from the Process tab, you won't see any messages being sent to your app.

Just like you can shut down Windows by clicking Start > Shutdown and Windows will shut down gracefully or you can just pull the plug from the wall and the computer is shut off immediately.

There is nothing you can do if the application is terminated from the Process tab.

Comment: From Windows 8 onwards, there is no 'End process', but only 'End task', and it just kill your task, no events are fired(tested with navigator.sendBeacon() on Windows 10, by ending Chrome).

Answer (score 4):

Closing the application from the application tab asks the application to close, so your teardown code is executed, closing the application from the process tab simply kills it, without any fuss, no application code is executed. You can't do anything about it.

Comment: but tell me one thing when i click on the END Task from APPLication TAB in the Task Manger then my Event is fired i the application but when i click on the END PRocess then Event is not fired

Comment: This is the way it is supposed to work. Nothing you can do about it.

Comment: Then tell me which event i fired from the Process TAB on click END PROCESS from TASK MANAGER

Comment: I Am not Statisfied with ur answr

Comment: Lol. No event is fired.

Comment: End process kills the application from the outside, end task asks the application to close itself as Lev has described..